# If, if-else, and elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I know how to do an if statement and elif statement but in this particular code i don't know how. What im trying to do exactly is when the user puts either female or male and a temperature it will show an outfit for that weather depending which gender is chosen. Can anyone help me?

```py
def main():
    
    print("Welcome to Outfitters Boulevard!")
    print()
    print("Where your next vacation outfit is just around the corner.")
    print("================================================")
    
    name = input("What is your name?")
    gender = input("Are you male or female?")
    favoriteColor = input("What is your favorite color?")
    temp = int(input("What is the temperature like where you're going?"))
    
    print(name + ", you mentioned that you're a female, your favorite color is " + favoriteColor + ",")
    print("and you're going somewhere with " + str(temp) + " weather.")
    print("We've got just the outfit for you: ")
    
    if temp>84:
        print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
    elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
        print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
    elif 55>=temp<= 69:
        print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
    elif temp <55: 
        print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
    
main()
```

Comment: Which outfit for which gender will show?

Comment: For "The perfect hot weather outfit" if the user was a female it would show shorts, sandals, sunhat and a crop shirt but if the user was a male it would show a hawaiian shirt, shorts and flip flops

Comment: Your comparison syntax is wrong. It should be `elif 70 <= temp  <= 84:`

Comment: Note also that in the print statement with "you mentioned that you're a female", you should be using the `gender` variable you got from input

Comment: @anonymous123 I have answered your question, using the examples that you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code to add nested if-statements and made it a little more user-friendly. I added the items like you asked and also guided you on how you would write other items:

```py
def main():
    
    print("Welcome to Outfitters Boulevard!")
    print()
    print("Where your next vacation outfit is just around the corner.")
    print("================================================")
    
    name = input("What is your name?")
    gender = input("Are you male or female or other?")
    favoriteColor = input("What is your favorite color?")
    temp = int(input("What is the temperature like where you're going?"))
    
    print(name + ", you mentioned that you're a female, your favorite color is " + favoriteColor + ",")
    print("and you're going somewhere with " + str(temp) + " weather.")
    print("We've got just the outfit for you: ")
    
    if temp>84:
        print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
        if gender.casefold() == 'male':
            # Show male outfits here
            print("Hawaiian shirt, shorts and flip flops")

        elif gender.casefold() == 'female':
            # Show female outfits here
            print("Shorts, sandals and a crop shirt.")

        else:
            # Show other outfits here

    elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
        print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
        if gender.casefold() == 'male':
            # Show male outfits here

        elif gender.casefold() == 'female':
            # Show female outfits here

        else:
            # Show other outfits here

    elif 55>=temp<= 69:
        print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
        if gender.casefold() == 'male':
            # Show male outfits here

        elif gender.casefold() == 'female':
            # Show female outfits here

        else:
            # Show other outfits here

    elif temp <55: 
        print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
        if gender.casefold() == 'male':
            # Show male outfits here

        elif gender.casefold() == 'female':
            # Show female outfits here

        else:
            # Show other outfits here
    
main()
```

The `casefold()` method makes sure that capitals do not matter so the user can answer the gender question with varying capitals and still get to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the gender typed has to be either `male` or `female`, this should work.

On a sidenote this code is not very pretty and I recommend looking up f-strings to parse strings.

```
def main():
    
    print("Welcome to Outfitters Boulevard!")
    print()
    print("Where your next vacation outfit is just around the corner.")
    print("================================================")
    
    name = input("What is your name?")
    gender = input("Are you male or female?")
    favoriteColor = input("What is your favorite color?")
    temp = int(input("What is the temperature like where you're going?"))
    
    print(name + ", you mentioned that you're a female, your favorite color is " + favoriteColor + ",")
    print("and you're going somewhere with " + str(temp) + " weather.")
    print("We've got just the outfit for you: ")

    # If it is a male
    if gender == "male":
       if temp>84:
          print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
       elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
          print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
       elif 55>=temp<= 69:
          print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
       elif temp <55: 
          print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
    # if it is a female
    elif gender == "female":
       if temp>84:
          print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
       elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
          print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
       elif 55>=temp<= 69:
          print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
       elif temp <55: 
          print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
    # If the gender is not correct
    else:
       print(f"Gender has to be male or female (found {gender})")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes made in the conditions as well as added a `gender` check:

```
print("Welcome to Outfitters Boulevard!")
print()
print("Where your next vacation outfit is just around the corner.")
print("================================================")

name = input("What is your name?")
gender = input("Are you male or female?")
favoriteColor = input("What is your favorite color?")
temp = int(input("What is the temperature like where you're going?"))

if gender.lower() == "yes":
    gender = "female"
else:
    gender = "male"
print(name + ", you mentioned that you're a " + gender + ", your favorite color is " + favoriteColor + ",")
print("and you're going somewhere with " + str(temp) + " weather.")
print("We've got just the outfit for you: ")

if temp > 84:
    print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
elif temp >= 70 and temp <= 84:
    print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
elif temp >= 55 and temp <= 69:
    print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
elif temp < 55: 
    print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
```

OUTPUT:

```
================================================                                                                                                                             
What is your name?dirtybit                                                                                                                                                   
Are you male or female?no                                                                                                                                                    
What is your favorite color?black                                                                                                                                            
What is the temperature like where you're going?75                                                                                                                           
dirtybit, you mentioned that you're a male, your favorite color is black,                                                                                                     
and you're going somewhere with 75 weather.                                                                                                                                  
We've got just the outfit for you:                                                                                                                                           
The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit
```

Comment: How is the user meant to know to input 'yes' or 'no' for the question: `Are you male or female?` I do not see how this part makes sense?

Comment: I'm sure you misread `Are you male or female?` as `Are you female?`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest multiple if-statements:

```
if gender == "female":
    if temp>84:
        print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
    elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
        print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
    elif 55>=temp<= 69:
        print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
    elif temp <55: 
        print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
else:
    if temp>84:
        print("The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit")
    elif 70 >=temp<= 84:
        print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
    elif 55>=temp<= 69:
        print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
    elif temp <55: 
        print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
```

Answer (score 0):

use `and`. in your case, it can be

```
elif temp >= 70 and temp <= 84:
    print("The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit")
elif temp 55 >= and temp <= 69:
    print("The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit")
elif temp < 55: 
    print("The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add an `if` statement to 
make the outputted outfit name be **customized for males and females**:

```
def main():
    
    print("Welcome to Outfitters Boulevard!\n")
    print("Where your next vacation outfit is just around the corner.")
    print("================================================")
    
    name = input("What is your name?")
    gender = input("Are you male or female?")
    favoriteColor = input("What is your favorite color?")
    temp = int(input("What is the temperature like where you're going?"))
    
    print(f"{name}, you mentioned that you're a female, your favorite color is {favoriteColor},")
    print(f"and you're going somewhere with {temp} weather.")
    print("We've got just the outfit for you: ")
    
    if gender == 'female': # Here is where the customization begins
        gender = 'For Women'
    else:
        gender = 'For Men'
    if temp > 84:
        print(f"The Perfect Hot Weather Outfit {gender}")
    elif 70 <= temp <= 84:
        print(f"The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit {gender}")
    elif 55 <= temp <= 69:
        print(f"The Perfect Cool Weather Outfit {gender}")
    elif temp < 55: 
        print(f"The Perfect Cold Weather Outfit {gender}")
    
main()
```

Input:

```
What is your name? Ann Zen
Are you male or female? female
What is your favorite color? red
What is the temperature like where you're going? 70
```

Output:

```
Ann Zen, you mentioned that you're a female, your favorite color is red,
and you're going somewhere with 70 weather.
We've got just the outfit for you: 
The Perfect Warm Weather Outfit For Women
```

*(note: You've goth the strict inequality operators mixed up, which I fixed here.)*